# Internal server error when rejecting draft

Tags: bug, documentation

I tried to reject [this draft](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/13820), because the topic was not about debugging.

Rejecting caused a POST request to `/documentation/javascript/drafts/13573/reject-draft`, which responded with a 302 Found response. It then loaded `https://stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/documentation/javascript/drafts/13573/reject-draft` with a get request, which returned a 500 internal server error.

Request times were somewhere between 11:50-11:55 GMT I think.

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/31899389#31899389